# Megaraid controller: one slot seems dead

Tags: raid

I have a workstation with a raid controller LSI MegaRAID SAS 9271-8i. The problem is that the slot n°4 (with a new hard drive) shows no led activity at all, and the command `megacli -LdPdInfo -a0`, for slot number 4, returns `PD: 4 Information` without any other info, while the other slots show a lot of info about the other drives. If I try to make it offline, mark it as missing or mark as prepared for removal, the result is `Adapter 0: Device at Enclosure - 252, Slot - 4 is not found`. If I remove physically the drive and I re-mount it, nothing happens. Thank you for your help